# Duplicate Search Results

Tags: discussion, search, vote-to-close

So why wouldn't #113300 be at least the first result in the drop-down, if not the only one, after typing its title exactly?  Does it use the same routines/indexes as the standard search?

[alt text http://www.sqeq.com/image/MSO_DupeSearch.gif](http://www.sqeq.com/image/MSO_DupeSearch.gif)

Comment: I didn't even know that box does a text search. I always punch in the question number.

Comment: Yeah, it's easier sometimes to just type the title instead of just going to find the ID.  Makes me want to see the ID in the list of existing close votes on a question.

Comment: ... or something like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21826/greasemonkey-easier-vote-to-close-for-duplicates

Comment: @squillman: the ID is in the URL; if you're using a browser like Firefox, point at (hover over) the question link.  the URL is shown in the status bar at the bottom of the browser window.  easy-peasy.

Comment: How do you expect us to find anything on your image without some freehand circles? Sheesh... :-)

Comment: Search is hard, let's go shopping!

Comment: @tvanfosson: 1000 pardons for my gross ineptitude!  Fixed :)

Comment: @squillman -- thanks.  I see it now. :-)