# Search results are being duplicated/triplicated/quadruplicated

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Note: This is a different issue from [Duplicate Search Results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39972/duplicate-search-results); this seems to be related to the new engine.

While preparing to answer a meta question on Seasoned Advice, I did a [search for coffee](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=coffee).  At a glance:

- "Reusing coffee grounds" appears on pages 1, 2, and 3
- "How do you reduce static in a coffee grinder?" appears on pages 1, 3, 4, and 5
- "What factors lead to rich crema on espresso? " appears on pages 1, 2, 4, and 5

*(Note: Change your display to 50 results per page to see this)*

Basically it is just showing the same search results over and over again.

Basically it is just showing the same search results over and over again.

Basically it is just showing the same search results over and over again.

Is a fix forthcoming?

Comment: P.S. I'm sure this is happening on all the sites; I used this one as an example because the relatively low number of results makes it very obvious.

Comment: Is answering questions on cooking meta so exhausting that you need to search for coffee for that?

Comment: @balpha: It actually used to be, during the first few weeks.  But no, it's a quiet place now, I just went to look it up because someone asked a question about it.

Comment: yep, seeing it too!

Comment: My random guess is that lucene is returning hits for the individual answers for some reason.

Comment: @Zor That's definitely a possibility, although some of the questions in the results have 8-10 answers that all have the keyword "coffee", so I would have expected even *more* repetition.

Comment: The issue is indeed we're looking for answers for rolling up to questions in these cases, I'll add a distinct pass when we do this in a push likely Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for this will go our next build.  What was happening is that when presenting questions, if we're finding multiple answers and rolling up to questions we may see duplication (not on the same page, for other reasons).  This wasn't an issue before in SQL, but now that we're in Lucene joining *back* to SQL, it is.

I just checked in a distinct filter pass (keeping search result order) to eliminate this duplication bug, marking as completed.