# Search results being duplicated (again)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

*This [seems to have been addressed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77575/139256), despite the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag I'm seeing this again, so I'm resubmitting this. I didn't see any more recent postings of this of this issue.*

The new search tool appears to return the same question/answer many times over. Check out [this search for "crystalized honey" on Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?q=crystalized+honey); almost each answer is shown at least twice. I assume this isn't intended behavior.

Comment: Either I'm blind, or there's no duplication on that search? (I'm not discounting the first option...). Sure, each question appears in the list multiple times, but each entry is for a different *post* within that question.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for pointing that out, I honestly didn't notice that. Further discussion under Gamecat's answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you get the duplicates, because some results point to an answer and some results point to a question. Both have the same title, but there is a **Q:** or an **A:** in the summary.

Example for the cooking result:

Result 1 is the question: [Why doesn't acacia honey crystallize?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24943/why-doesnt-acacia-honey-crystallize), result 4 is an [answer to the same question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24943/why-doesnt-acacia-honey-crystallize/24980#24980).

Comment: The new search is great, but it's harder to tell questions and answers apart, not to mention individual answers to the same question.

Comment: Agree, the Q and A could be more visible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters apparently [that was intentional](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange#comment469338_161577) *It's the only option really without being even more jarring since other result types besides questions and answers will appear later, mixing more than 3+ types of result formats is...yeah.*

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. I can't see the point, though, given that once I'm on a page, I'll (almost) certainly look at the other answers to see what they suggest. Why take up valuable space on the search results page to show me stuff I'm likely to see anyway?