# Group search results by question

Tags: feature-request, search

Can search results be grouped by what question they came from? It is currently quite confusing to have questions and their answers right next to each other.

Here is an example of the confusion caused by this (a search on my own name!):

---

> [image]

---

I know this is because they are different posts, but it is kind of confusing and it clutters the results. How about adding a little arrow next to the most relevant result and getting rid of the others on the same question? Then when you click the arrow it expands to show more results on that question. Like this:

> [see more on this question <kbd>></kbd>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164396/)

Or there could be some other way to expand or show more. This is just a thing that's been  annoying me and clutters up the search results.

This problem may also cause [confusion about duplication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163236/).

TL;DR: Arrow next to most relevant result that expands to show more relevant results from that question/answer.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree with this proposal - I agree the many result case is confusing (though handling it across pages is fairly complicated too), but the exact layout needs to wait until the search result layout is final.  We will likely do another pass at making vote/answer counts more visible since that's the most vocal complaint.  The past few weeks we've just been very busy moving the sites back to NY (almost done), then search will continue to get more love, promise!

Comment: @NickCraver Any status on this thus far? At the moment Google is far more useful than SO search (`site:stackoverflow.com search terms "in quotes" -without -these -words etc.`). :O

Comment: @NickCraver Still no status? Maybe the search engine should just be replaced with a Google custom search

Comment: We'll get to it...it's far from the only item on our plate and it's not an easy solution either. Keep in mind smart remarks don't help.

Comment: @NickCraver Nothing? I know there's a lot of work to do, but it's been 3 months....

Comment: we can't do this without an elasticsearch upgrade which isn't released yet, so no...no progress here, and still very, very many things going on.

Comment: @NickCraver ping: is there any update on this?

Comment: Just wanted to ask the same question. I didn't even realized in the beginning when searching and came to ask myself: Didn't I read this already? Now I need to focus to skip an already opened answer. Why would I read only one answer not taking a look at what others suggested (since I have to scroll up to the question anyway).