# New search has a few redundant results

Tags: feature-request, search

New search has had it's [share](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161577/111307) of complaints

I'm not sure I like the `Q:`, `A:` prefixes.

For one, there are now redundant search results here:

[image]

At first I thought, you should at least group them:

[image]

(that UI with the > is horrible, I'm just showing the idea)

But I don't even like that.  You're missing the point that search results are *links to threads*, not links to individual questions or answers.  The `Q` and `A` prefixes don't help much, because when clicking a `Q` you are only hoping to find a reasonable `A`.

Also there's too much text in the results!  I really honestly never read more than the title, you click the link to check it out.

A really bad situation is when links to the same thread are dispersed throughout the search results.  This really needs to be fixed.

[image]

Threads are *related*.  It's kind of odd to see a `Q:` for a thread, then some time later see an `A:` for that same thread.  It's like the search engine doesn't even know they are related.

Comment: wow, i never noticed the Q: and A:, probably part of the reason I stopped using SO's search and now just Google (since the search update).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164396/group-search-results-by-question