# Search should combine questions and answers by default

Tags: feature-request, search

Currently, if you use the SE search the results contain both, questions and answers by default. The result of that is that the search results contain many duplicates, which I find rather annoying.

You can work around that by using `is:question` as a search parameter, but that is not an ideal solution and also not very obvious to new users.

The ideal default would be in my opinion to search both questions and answers for the search terms, but to combine the results so that each question appears only once. Each result would represent the question *and* all its answers, so each result would be more like a page, not a single post.

If you would specify `is:question` or `is:answer` or any other question/answer-specific search option, it would revert to the current one post per result display.

Comment: dup: [Group search results by question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164396/group-search-results-by-question)

Comment: @Doorknob It's not exactly the same idea, I wan't to completely hide the fact that a result represents more than one post, the linked post proposes to add a mechanism to expand each result into posts, which I don't think is necessary at all. But the general idea is of course very similar.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163398/13295

Comment: This isn't something we disagree with on the display side, but technically it's another issue altogether - it's a major architecture and indexing shift we have to fully evaluate before changing.

Comment: Google Translate says... 6-8 weeks ;p