# Flag as Not A Dupe

Tags: feature-request, flags, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

Would it be possible to get a *Not a dupe* flag, for questions which have been closed as duplicate?

Every now and again I'll see [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169489/search-should-combine-questions-and-answers-by-default) that are completely different, and definitely not dupes.

**A new flag would save me typing in the *Other* box every time.**

Comment: I can see potential for misuse. Perhaps it should only be available to say... 2K+ users?

Comment: And perhaps it could be called... "vote to reopen". ;)

Comment: @J.Steen If you're saying that something like this already exists, I don't see the option: http://i.imgur.com/Fr2CKnf.png If you're just suggesting the name, I like it.

Comment: @DannyBeckett You don't have that privilege yet http://i.imgur.com/fqq1WBU.png

Comment: @DannyBeckett It's a feature available to 3k+ users - at the same time they get the ability to cast close-votes. Sorry, I have a habit of being overly sarcastic before I've had my morning coffee. =)

Comment: @Bart Nice! ...but a flag would still be good for <3k users ;)

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Flag > Other works just fine. (And it's 3k for close privs.)

Comment: @Mat Okay, I give in... can somebody write an answer?

Comment: @DannyBeckett Would you downvote me as well if I answered this? Given that it's essentially what Nullpointer told you to do?

Comment: @Bart Maybe... depends if you tell me to write it in *Other* ;) But seriously, if J.Steen's comment can be converted, that's a good answer. **Edit:** Too bad I can't downvote Back in a Flash's answer for the same reason. No votes left today.

Comment: Suppose there will be such flag option. You will still have to *explain* why it's not a dupe, you can't expect moderators to spend their time trying to figure out themselves. So this pretty much renders the "save me typing" irrelevant. Bottom line: can't see any reason to have this in place.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah that's a fair point...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "vote to reopen" feature already exists, and is available to users with 3000 reputation or more. You get it bundled in the privilege to cast votes - be it to close or reopen.

Before that, all you can do is as you've done up until now; flag, and write a clear explanation in the *Others* field.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly why we have reopen votes. If a question is closed (by mistake/oversight) users with the privilege can [vote to reopen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) the question. On (Meta) Stack Overflow you will need a reputation >3k to obtain this privilege.

Until then you can just use a custom flag if you really feel a big mistake has been made. Simply go for the "Other" option and clearly describe the situation. ("Not a dupe" is not enough ;) )

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bart! Unfortunately can't upvote until tomorrow.

Comment: @DannyBeckett I'll do it for you. ;)

Comment: Cheers @J.Steen !

Answer (score 0):

You can flag such closed question; and add custom comment in the **needs moderator attention** section.