# Dear Stack Exchange: a statement and a letter from your moderators

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators

## Dear Stack Exchange, Inc.,

We know you know about this already, so we'll keep this brief. The past two weeks have been rough. Lots of moderators have lost confidence in you; for some, it was the final straw. For many of us, though, we like being here and we don't want it to get to that point. So, in the past few days, a number of us have collaborated on writing you a letter.

We're worried about the direction that the company has been taking recently, and we're concerned that nobody in management has noticed or addressed that. The past couple of weeks have been the catalyst, finally, for us to write it all down in one place.

So, without further ado - please take 10 minutes out of your day to **[read the letter in full](https://dearstack.artofcode.co.uk/)**. It's not short, but we think it's important feedback that the company (and management in particular) needs to hear. Those of us who've already seen your [recent meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps) seem to be of the opinion that it's a good first step, and it's certainly touched on a number of the issues we've mentioned here, but there's plenty more work to do. We hope we can start working together with you again to get back to building communities.

*Signed,*
*855 moderators, ex-moderators, and users*.

---

**Staff:** Please do share this letter around the company. We think it's important that we have a shared goal, and to do that we need to start from some common ground.

**Everyone:** If you wish to sign this letter in support of the sentiments in it, you're welcome to do so - use the button at the bottom of the page. If you have your own further thoughts on the things we've touched on in this letter, feel free to use the answers here to add to the discussion.

Comment: Oh, my.  It even has its own domain name.  Was this drafted by only those folks who kept their diamonds?

Comment: Can a mod [featured] this?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I believe so, yes. I believe a couple of people may have submitted resignations but they were not processed yet.

Comment: After reading the letter I have concluded that the new apology is very much based off this letter. I'm not exactly sure how to feel about that at this moment in time. I guess time will tell.

Comment: I'm glad to see this conspiracy of light paid off.and the simple answer @script47 is we suck at conspiring and most of this was done in various parts of SE chat. Folks kinda probably evesdropped.

Comment: @Script47 the communicated way to request *featured* is to modflag it. I have done this now.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I did mod flag it but I left a comment on the off chance a mod turned up and saw the post before my flag.

Comment: I declined to sign this letter when it circulated to me yesterday (partly because I'm not a moderator, just a pseudonymous vulture with a big beak on crypto.se, but also) partly because it doesn't call for much in the way of specific actions by SO.inc or set down specific criteria by which to judge a response by SO.inc.  I agree with most of the sentiment, but when collectively bargaining with SO.inc, [we must take care not to lose sight of real commitments and power structures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334573) among any sentimental platitudes offered to make us feel better.

Comment: You are getting the Great Question badge within just a few hours for a question posted in a Sunday. That is quite an achievement!

Comment: I signed this. It's not perfect, it doesn't capture my sentiments exactly, and it doesn't hold SE to a specific set of measurable standards, but it's close enough. Thanks to those who drafted it.

Comment: Thanks for the work on this [guys](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/19078/6807). I wrote [a few thoughts about this letter with an eye specifically toward the sites I used to moderate](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6733/30). TL;DR: ⓐ I fully support the call to acknowledge and rectify the public defamation issue and process Monica's case properly; but ⓑ the letter does not even begin to represent the other core issue that caused mine and other resignations.

Comment: Dear moderators, nice read but I really hope that's it's not just all talking but also action and consequences if the desired things do not happen.

Comment: Why avoiding mentioning LGBT issues which started it all in the letter? Or I missed it? That's the only reason I picked signing the lavender letter compare to this one, due to lacking in some key area which caused all this mess in the first place.

Comment: @AnkitSharma see [terdon's comment below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334575/dear-stack-exchange-a-statement-and-a-letter-from-your-moderators?noredirect=1#comment1096176_334577)

Comment: @ArtOfCode why not mention other letter in the question itself?

Comment: @AnkitSharma see [terdon's comment below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334575/dear-stack-exchange-a-statement-and-a-letter-from-your-moderators?noredirect=1#comment1096176_334577)

Comment: Just a small nitpick about the signature feature... It directs to Stack Overflow for the account verification. I don't have a Sack Overflow account (nor do I really want one as I am not a programmer/tech person). While SO is the company and not SE, might it be better (probably not possible at this point) to use Meta (I guess not everyone may have a Meta account either) for account verification?

Comment: @Skooba I don't have any control over that; it's just how the API works. You may blame SE for the SO-centricness :)

Comment: @ArtOfCode 10-4, we all know SO is where the big $ is at XD. Know that if I don't get around to actually signing it, I do support it.

Comment: I put my sig on it too, up to 345 names now.

Comment: @Skooba Apparently you can hack the link to sign in via Meta Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: I said this in the thread on Teams but wanted to say here as well. Thank you for getting this together, we are working on a response.

Comment: @SaraChipps - Please, do yourself (and the rest of us) a favor, and try these two steps first: (1) admit you botched this, and (2) reinstate Monica's moderator status. Do those two things first, and I think you'll find the community will be much more receptive to whatever response you have been working on.

Comment: I wonder why this post still hasn't been `[featured]`. Clearly mods/employees have seen it.

Comment: @mbomb007 IIRC it has been mentioned that staff actively knew regarding this letter and its contents too (at least to some extent). Not to mention the preemptive nature of that post and this post.

Comment: @mbomb007 This letter was being worked on before the apology was. Please read the editor's note at the top of the letter.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson [status-unable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334575/dear-stack-exchange-a-statement-and-a-letter-from-your-moderators#comment1096403_334575)

Comment: @Script47 priorities. The company won't feature external content, no matter how important, while they have their own content featured.

Comment: @Shadow then I guess I'm wondering why my flag hasn't been declined.

Comment: @Script47 all my custom flags before mods were appointed took **at least** two weeks, sometimes half a year. And these days it must be even worse, since they're all busy in the place being on fire. :/

Comment: @Caleb I'm aware the system doesn't allow you to flag your own comments. My point was that there's no reason to flag your own comments as "No Longer Needed", because the *only* reason to use that flag is if you think the comment should be deleted. But, the system allows you to delete your own comments whenever you want (except, I believe, on posts which are locked). There's no reason to be flagging for a moderator to do something you can immediately do yourself.

Comment: Given that the press has miss-identified the nature of the signers I suggest splitting the mod vs. user signatory count both in this post and visually on the site.

Comment: @Caleb I've issued a correction notice to them, and the wording has since been changed.

Comment: "*451 moderators, ex-moderators, and users.*" is the temperature at which SE catches fire and burns?

Comment: @VLAZ 494 now. [128 more](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=494+%C2%B0F) and the lead pipes for the extinguishing water melt.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Have you ever seen any response from this coming from anyone within SE's staff? Or they just ignored all of us as usual?

Comment: @VictorStafusa See [Sara's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334575/dear-stack-exchange-a-statement-and-a-letter-from-your-moderators?noredirect=1#comment1096762_334575). At the moment, that's the last I've heard - they're still working on a response. I've heard likewise in the mod team.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Seems to be just a dismissive comment to try to cool things down without actually saying anything at all.

Comment: @SaraChipps, It was a week ago you promised a response to this; is that still forthcoming?  ETA?

Comment: Hi Nate, we are working on the draft now. We want to be thoughtful in how we approach just as you were all clearly very thoughtful in putting it together. Some of that involves changing how we do some things, so we're getting our ducks in a row to make sure we can back up any commitments we make.

Comment: ducks learn the row thing faster than this... maybe one duck just doesn't fit in the row?

Comment: @SaraChipps It look 9 days for you to start  (your comment posted when it was including the word "now" makes it seem like it was started on or very close to October 15th). It's now been another 11 days still without any response, and I really need to ask - how long does it take to write a response? I get that writing it takes time, and I get that you have a lot of fires to put out, but unless you worry about the core(s) of the fire, no matter how many small fires you put out, there'll always be new ones popping up faster than you can handle.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl To be fair, there _is_ a response from SE in the answers here, posted a few days ago. Apparently there's more to come, but we'll have to see on that score.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I'm aware. The "more to come" part is the one I'm worried about, because while they're writing that, there's still new fires popping up elsewhere, and it still feels like communication is breaking down in the feedback threads. They've kept their promises so far, but the entire situation seems to be affected heavily by inertia from SE's side while the community is bouncing from issue to issue faster than SE is keeping up. Management concerns aside, there's a point where this looks more like bad planning and coordination than struggling to keep up because of volume.

Comment: Hi @SaraChipps, It's been a month since this was posted and three weeks since your most recent comment -- are you guys still working on a response to this?  How much longer should we expect to wait?

Comment: @NateS-ReinstateMonica 6-8.

Comment: @NateS-ReinstateMonica Let's not forget the (`till now) [5 podcasts](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/) Ms. Chipps has found the time to participate in, each one clocking in at about 38 minutes

Comment: @SaraChipps For being self-declared understaffed with over 250 employees, you're shockingly awful at strategizing your schedules to get the most out of it while handling the community in an efficient manner. It's abundantly clear at this point you do have time - just stop with the lies already and try to be open with your community, and you might actually have one when this mess ends. You're currently pushing away everyone with your actions - including the groups you wanted to "protect" (and I'm saying "protect" because the way you've done it has sure as hell not been protecting us).

Comment: @SaraChipps You personally have time to go on podcasts, you (the company) have time to spew out articles on the blog and not to forget organizing the podcasts. I highly doubt that takes 38 minutes. You personally obviously have [time to tweet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335173/332043) and talk to the media, all of this fast, but you (the company) don't have time to respond to your own community? In case you haven't noticed, [multiple sites in the network are falling apart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/332043), and

Comment: @SaraChipps [Monica is preparing to take legal action](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users) because you (the company) couldn't do something as simple as defend your own position. I have no idea what you're doing, but if  you don't start prioritizing responding to the main part of your site (the community), it will fall apart until you don't have one. I hope more and more Charcoal will suspend operations, and you might see the importance when the site starts flooding with spam. You're running out of time.

Comment: @SaraChipps And in spite of presumably getting this reminder quite often, you (personally or the company, I really have no clue) still don't respond. You (personally) should take a trick out of Shog's book [and actually reply to status requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388313/experiment-ended-closing-and-reopening-happens-at-3-votes-for-the-next-30-day#comment729227_388313). From the outside, you appear to not be doing anything, and ignoring the community in the process. The second you open up even a little, that changes enough for there to still be hope something is coming.

Comment: @SaraChipps The SE network and your "flagship", Stack Overflow, is effectively a living organism consisting of tens of millions of "cells", and with mods being the immune system - and you shot it. Now it's bleeding users and mods while cells outside the blood stream are dying. This will continue spreading because of the fantastic transport system that powers communication - the internet. You (the company) took shots at a massive organism consisting of so many different types of cells and expected it to be fine, but instead, it's shutting down because different components depend on each other.

Comment: @SaraChipps while that's happening, you're (the company) appearing to be ignoring the issues: effectively the perfect, real representation of the "this is fine" meme (also added as an Easter egg to chat).my point is that SE consists of so many different people and systems that depend on each other. There's tens of millions of users, and instead of going about this carefully and informing the users, you (the company) shot the organism and sat down to watch it bleed out and collapse. It's still bleeding - do something before there's nothing left

Comment: @SaraChipps The community is screaming out, telling you there's something wrong. Actually, that there's lots of things wrong, yet, there's no response to be found on a lot of these issues. The cells start communicating the only way they can when there's a danger, and awareness spreads. New problems arise because this living organism is communicating at the speed of light, and it's now reaching out of the building for help. Monica? Legal action. (Some) other users (including me for the next roughly a week)? Spreading the news off-site, hoping the media picks it up to turn up the pressure.

Comment: There's countless examples of various actions being taken, and you (the company) still just sit there. Start communicating again, and you might be able to adapt your own points to a better received version of your own ideas, with nearly the same or exactly the same meaning. If you (the company) don't, @SaraChipps, the community will find its own explanations, and it'll hurt you (the company).

Comment: @Zoe I understand your frustration, but... please stop. Or at least, not here, where I get a notification every few hours because you're still pissed off.

Comment: @Zoe that's fine. Just please do it somewhere I don't get pinged every single time.

Comment: oh, right. Sorry, I forgot it had that effect.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Would you still get pinged if you made the post Community Wiki?

Comment: @faintsignal No, but only a moderator can do that, and I'd rather they didn't.

Comment: Sorry Art of Code but messaging to the bounty benefactor. @Zoe do you think awarding the 7th bounty in a row to Heather's answer is attracting that kind of support you are hoping for? Are you looking for a way to award all your rep to one person, is that it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm going to push a bounty per day until I either run out of rep, or risk the downvoting privilege (and by extension, the commenting privilege) until I leave. It's gonna go to Heather's answer unless an official answer is posted, in which case it'll go to that one (provided it's not awful obviously). I'm not looking to attract support in any other way than by making the situation here more visible, and what better way to do that than by a daily bump? It risks reaching the same group over and over, but why not? Everything is a longshot at this point, and I got 3 more days on the site

Comment: Moreover, it's my worthless virtual internet points I'm giving away. I'm going to channel it into a question of a high enough significance to turn up the heat, on the off chance that's going to be a triggering factor for an answer from SE (/cc @SaraChipps now that I'm already commenting). The answer I see the most value to here is the other letter - that's my opinion and my decision based on my likely flawed reasoning that I can do anything to even make a dent in the mountain known as SE. I'll make a final bounty on Friday that I'll leave up until it expires or gets auto-awarded.

Comment: @zoe Good for you. It's good you've explained yourself but before leaving why not convert all these comments into a proper answer that way even if the answer gets deleted it will remain visible to 10k users.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because I have a lot of emotions and opinions coming into play, and I'm currently very emotional because it's come to the point where I don't see any other way out but leaving (for various reason I don't want to discuss in the comments on a question where OP has asked for fewer pings :] ). I'm planning to post something at some point before I leave, but I need to be careful with how I write it so it doesn't turn into a rant. If I can't avoid that, I won't post anything.

Comment: **SE added a feedback survey**: [Info](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/), [**Survey**](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/Z2YDMRD). This is your chance to give them your feedback.

Comment: @mbomb007 Oh, I have. That's not what we meant here.

Comment: I can't access the letter anymore (just wanted to reread it). Does anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: @Trilarion Something pegged my server's CPU and knocked it offline. Back up.

Comment: Finally able to mark this as [tag:status-completed]. Thanks all for your participation. Looking forward to hearing from y'all more in the future.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Teresa Dietrich, the Head of Product and Community at Stack Overflow, has posted on [the company’s commitment to rebuilding the relationship with you, our community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343890/51) which (in addition to the other points that it covers), is intended to serve as a response to the Dear Stack Exchange open letter referenced above.

Thank you to all of the moderators and users who took the time to write out your feelings in such a meaningful way. I am sorry that it took so long to respond. I hope that the response can serve as a basis for some closure and for the chance to start anew.

Comment: Thank you for your help in getting things to this point. I think without your point of contact within the company, a lot of people would be at a utter loss.

Comment: By unaccepting and switching to this answer, the lavender letter is significantly less visible...which still hasn't been responded to, I'll note.

Comment: @heather and this is why different topics should be on different questions. [Which they already are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336731/643262), so I do not see the problem.

Comment: @heather in addition to what wimi said, also please see [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343890/the-company-s-commitment-to-rebuilding-the-relationship-with-you-our-community#comment1151986_343890) from Teresa on her post, responding to doppelgreener. Hopefully things are moving in the right direction for this issue as well.

Answer (score 208):

When you're reading through the vast outpouring of concern from our community - whether that be this letter, the comments/answers on your apology announcement(s), the 40+ meta questions as a result of this recent incident, or the vast backlog of requests over the past few years - I ask you to consider the **human impact**.

It would be very easy to chalk down this entire incident to *just another controversy*. Just another meta post. Just another loss of a few long-time users. Just another blip in our turnover statistics. Just another weekend of overtime for the community managers. Just another 'apology' post to please the masses for a few more weeks. I can understand why you'd look at it this way - that's what corporations do.

But please, **don't ignore the real-world, lasting impact this is going to have on your users**.

If there's one paragraph of the open letter that you should read, it's this:

> Among the most serious mistakes made was that a staff member spoke to the press about a member of the community who participates here under her own name. That same community member is now described in the press with language that can be taken to imply she is an extremist and a bigot. This news article is now the top search report for her name, which may cause her serious issues in real life, with her friends, her family, and her career. In doing this, Stack Exchange has rewarded years of service by putting one of its volunteers in danger – and there’s now a very real feeling that we may no longer be safe on this platform.

One of our most valued moderators is going to find their name permanently tarnished. If you were considering hiring a person, and noticed that the top search result for their name painted them as a transphobe, would you proceed any further? Would you try and find out the whole story? Or would you simply cross their name off the 'potential candidates' list and move on? Because that's what'll happen. Their life, affected in a real and lasting way, as a result of your decision. And I don't think that's fair.

But it's not only the moderator in question that will be impacted by this. Consider all the other moderators who spend hours every day moderating this site, for weeks and years on end, only to find their valuable time unappreciated. The vast collection of active users who feel lost in the community in which they once felt at home. And the LGBTQ+ users who have been insulted, belittled, and dehumanised by recent events, to a point where they feel unsafe participating on these sites.

Think of that. Think of the human impact. It's all that I ask.

Comment: As a user and moderator who participates under their* real name, I think this is a particularly important point. Going public with her real name was a grave mistake that probably caused real personal and financial harm.

Comment: * I used "their" quite intentionally.

Comment: @CareyGregory - I am not sure whether to read your comment as saying that the "grave mistake" is on the part of Monica for using her real name on SE or on the part of SE for revealing it to the press.

Comment: @AlexReinking I definitely meant SE's part.

Comment: @AlexReinking: In this case, the employee shouldn't have answered the journalist's question. Period.

Answer (score 151):

> This is a second drafted letter (also drafted before the meta post) addressing more specifically the issues the LGBT+ community feels it is necessary to address. **You can read this letter in full and sign it [on the same website as the primary letter](https://dearstack.artofcode.co.uk/lavender)**. Signatures are welcome from both members and allies of the LGBTQ+ community. Thank you.

### Dear Stack Exchange, Inc.,

We, the undersigned moderators and users of the Stack Exchange network, feel that it is necessary to elaborate on a few points that were omitted in our general letter, in order to keep that letter focused.

We are members and allies of the LGBTQ+ community, and we are hurt.

We are hurt that in the time since the announcement of change in the Code of Conduct was made, we felt unfairly targeted by transphobic attitudes that were dismissed as "friendly discussion", not only by the community at large but also by other moderators.

We are hurt that over the years, there have been multiple users and moderators who have stepped away from using the site because they felt unwelcome due to anti-LGBTQ+ behavior by the community (and sometimes even moderators). The affected users and moderators have given multiple testimonies to that effect, yet have received no response from Stack Exchange, Inc.

We are hurt at how long it has taken for us to be heard, and hurt by how now that we are being heard at all, it has been tainted by mishandling by Stack Exchange, Inc, causing the community to be doubtful of our goals.

We are hurt that resignations from LGBTQ+ moderators have only started to receive notice due to the uproar over a correlated issue.

We are human, we are hurt, we are tired, and we ask that Stack Exchange, and the community as a whole, listens to our concerns.

We ask that several things be done:

1. We ask that Stack Exchange, Inc does more to pay attention to the complaints and requests of the LGBTQ+ community and does more to ensure that rules are properly applied such that LGBTQ+ people are treated with the same respect everyone should be treated with.
2. We ask that the consequences for not respecting members of the community be more explicit, and be consistently carried out. Too many times have transphobic or homophobic comments gone by with no response from the Community Team, leaving LGBTQ+ individuals to explain their own validity again and again and again.
3. Moderating is hard, and the LGBTQ+ community has been underrepresented in media for long enough that many moderators do not know how to handle some specific situations. Some moderators have requested sensitivity training. This would help those who work so hard on behalf of the Stack Exchange community to receive the support and guidance they need to carry out their duties.

It is time for something to be done about a situation that has become, frankly, untenable. Please listen to us - each of us, individually. The ways we have been hurt vary, and the things we feel could improve the situation vary. Too many of us have already left because nothing has been done. Thank you.

> [Editor’s note: LGBT+, LGBTQ+, and similar are used interchangeably. We refer to the entire group of  gender, romantic, and sexual minorities, or the ‘Lavender’ community.]
>
> [Second editor’s note: This was written before the most recent meta post by the Stack Exchange team, and we thank them for their acknowledgement of the situation, in particular of the harm they have caused to the LGBTQ+ community on Stack Exchange. However, the issues addressed in this letter go beyond just the incident of the past week, and so we are still releasing this letter, both for transparency, and the broader commentary it contains.]

---

Please: [Sign on the actual letter here](https://dearstackexchange.com/lavender)

(As of this edit, there are over 175 signatures.)

Comment: I wrote in my resignation that "[Stack Exchange draws] vocal bigots from the woodwork with prompts to discussion, and then [vanishes], forcing us to decide between tacit approval through silence or defense of our own against an unchanging torrent of bigotry." This pattern of behavior repeated itself again through these events. My wound from the past week runs deeper than can be corrected in a single act or apology. At least now, after the flood of bigotry, I hope it is clear how widespread this issue is. But these harms will continue until the Stack is immediately reactive when it occurs.

Comment: This is excellent. One of the worst parts of this is that SE stirred up waves of bigotry while the CM team did nothing about it, leaving it up to a handful of users to defend their own humanity and even moderate discussions that were targeting them personally. SE staff needed to step in and make clear that the identity of other users was not up for debate. I’m encouraged by the latest meta post, but hope to see staff action that sets bounds around what’s open for discussion, what’s open to education for those willing to learn in good faith, and what we simply won’t be debating as a community

Comment: I hesitated to sign the original letter, because of some language that I found to be a bit "iffy". Though I am not part of the "lavender" folk, this new letter did seem to be perfect to my supportive ears. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm *almost perfect* - some part of the current kerfuffle was (IMO) due to placing too much weight on one form of pronoun, instead of being equally respectful of any form - whatever the person preferred - and without taking context into consideration. Again, though I am not the wounded party here, I do think a requirement for more clarification of the rules, and *that it be applied equally and take context into consideration* would be beneficial here. (Please do correct me if I am wrong about this!)

Comment: Thing I'm concerned most is, **Why separate people in different communities like *LGBTQ+* and *not LGBTQ+*?** People are people, it doesn't matter what is that they do, or any personal,private stuff. Why can't we treat everybody as humans and not profile each other with these hurtful separations?

Comment: @Vishwa we decided to have two separate letters for two main reasons: i) we wanted to keep both letters relatively short. Therefore, trying to include the LGBTQ+ points in the other letter would not have done them justice. They would have only been mentioned in passing and we felt they deserved more attention. ii) In both letters, we tried to express a position broad enough for many people to sign. That becomes very hard when you try to combine too many separate points. Joining the letters would have led to far fewer signatures. Some of us have only signed one or the other.

Comment: I believe this is the more important letter of the two, especially as the other seems to be a bit apologetic on the issues this one raises

Comment: I really appreciate this letter, and think it deserves its own post separate from the general letter. It will be easier to reference in the future with its own post, and unfortunately, we'll probably need to keep revisiting this.

Comment: The text of this post and the website differ in not insignificant ways. @ArtofCode can you update the website?

Comment: I don't understand why this is posted as an answer not a separate post, since it seems separate and confuses things.

Comment: I have to admit I'm somewhat taken aback to find there is a feeling of dissatisfaction at SE's treatment of the LGBT community, given that the recent uproar was linked to the strongly pro-LGBT stance on the CoC regarding pronouns, and SE's strong public/political stance on LGBT matters not to mention Joel himself. I had genuinely never heard any complaints the site fostered 'phobic attitudes. I saw a few complaints it was going too far the other way in fact and you might say those complaints are 'phobic but this post infers a much deeper cause?

Comment: Stack Exchange [has posted an official response to this letter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354978/responding-to-the-lavender-letter-and-commitments-moving-forward).

Comment: The url `dearstackexchange.com` is not functionning or is it my machine?

Comment: @Tim affiliation of whatever kind could be shown in the chat rooms, in the user profile or even in the user name ... think of all the people who use some variation on "reinstate Monica" in their username, for instance. Similar things could be done in this regard.

Comment: @Vishwa because equity and equality are not the same thing. Pretending differences do not exist, and that people are not in fact targeted because of differences, doesn't actually fix the problem.

See also: https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Colorblind  https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/625404/equity-vs-equality-what-is-the-difference  https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Concern_troll

Comment: @Tim for example: [1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/102884/should-i-mention-my-name-change-in-my-resume-when-it-would-expose-me-as-transge) [2](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/111424/gender-transition-as-a-starting-faculty-member-a-terrible-idea) [3](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9696/how-to-ask-find-out-if-people-are-interested-in-lgbt-dating-relationships)

Comment: // , For technical questions, it's incidental. But Geoffrey here has a point about the more touchy feely forums, where questions like #1 might even _depend_ on showing one's hand. Although I guess phrasing them in an objective way, rather than subjective, might help with that?

Answer (score 148):

I'm one of the moderators that helped draft, and then signed [this letter](https://dearstack.artofcode.co.uk/). I'd like to offer my personal take on things.

I joined [Stack Overflow in 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572/thomas-owens), in one of the first Beta waves when you needed to be invited. I was involved in Area 51 in the definition of some of the earliest sites in the Stack Exchange network, primarily [Software Engineering (where I'm user ID 4 and was elected as a community moderator in 2012)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4/thomas-owens).

When I became a moderator, the role of moderator was described in two different ways. Moderators were called "janitors" or "garbage collectors" or "human exception handlers". A large part of our role was to resolve issues in our community that the others could not. We had binding votes to handle the worst posts quickly and the ability to suspend users who could not follow the rules and norms of the community. However, there was also another part to our role - liaisons to the company. We had easy access to the community team and were expected to help them understand the nuances and details of the communities that we serve.

Over the years, especially in the almost 8 years that I've been a moderator, I've seen a lot of change. The network grew from 1 site to 3 sites to over 170 sites covering so many topics. However, in that same time period, the environment also changed. The company, naturally, grew up as well. There were a lot of growing pains. The engagement between staff and moderators was very high when I joined the moderation team, but decreased over time. Feature requests and bug reports and even discussions weren't as well addressed by staff as they used to be. And, as moderators, our role as liaisons decreased, I feel because of the lack of engagement between staff and moderators.

The past year or so, in my opinion, has seen the most disengagement between staff and moderators (and the broader community), with most interaction happening in proclamations of changes or in emergency situations.

I believe that this disengagement is the very root of many of the problems that the network has seen over the past months and years.

Unfortunately, at this moment in time, there are pressing concerns from various individuals and groups that need to be addressed. However, as they are addressed, I hope that we can return to a spirit of collaboration between the company and the users, with the moderators that have been appointed from or elected by each community returning to their roles as liaisons and community builders in addition to custodians of their sites.

Based on the announcement that Stack Exchange staff have made, the next week or two will be pivotal in demonstrating the first steps in a restoration of this fundamental collaborative relationship that has made Stack Overflow, and the rest of the Stack Exchange network, so successful. I truly hope that we can repair these issues.

Personally, I will be watching the words and actions of Stack Exchange very closely over the next weeks and months. I hope that [their most recent apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/572) marks the beginning of a new chapter and a return to what brought so many of us to Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Hey, I'm #4 on Christianity.SE and a mod - I wonder how many of us nuts there are out there.

Answer (score 109):

Thank you for writing to us about this. This isn’t our final response here, but in the interest of being transparent and keeping lines of communication open, we wanted to respond with something as soon as possible. While this isn’t the answer you’ve been looking for, we wanted to update you on some of what we have been doing and what we have been working towards as an answer to these letters.

Since you posted,

- We have created a clear policy for communicating with the press regarding moderator actions. This has been coded as [“No Comment”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335708/under-what-circumstances-will-stack-exchange-inc-share-private-sensitive-infor/335749#335749).
- We have shared our censure/removal and reinstatement processes for moderators with them for feedback last week. You can read more on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335508/monicas-situation-continues-unresolved-is-se-hoping-the-problem-just-goes-away/335607#335607). These should be ready for moderators to use, and publicly available on October 22nd.
- We are currently working on updating [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes) ([archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20191023011602/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes)) we posted to accompany the recent CoC changes, taking in mind and heavily basing it on the [community suggested one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335234/a-pronominal-proposal). We will share the [revised version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336364/what-does-the-code-of-conduct-say-about-pronouns) with the moderators by tomorrow - and hope to have the feedback incorporated and made public by October 22nd.

As part of reviewing this, we are also taking our time to improve our internal communication processes so that we, the CMs, can more effectively communicate between our coworkers and moderators and the community at large. As part of our response to these letters, we want to have more details on this; as it entails structural change, it may take a little while.

Here are the points that we heard loud and clear from the letter and plan to address. Moderators and the community feel:

- Distanced from us and unincluded in changes that affect your sites and roles.
- Frustrated with long-standing problems seeming like you need to erupt on Twitter before you get our attention.
- That the CoC changes give less autonomy and flexibility on how to moderate a diverse group of sites that are used by people from many different backgrounds.
- That we do not actively support our Moderators anymore, and thus placed you on shaky ground. Including serious concerns regarding our statements made to the press.
- That it is not safe or acceptable anymore, even dangerous, to disagree with Stack Exchange on matters of major policy.
- That you want to see a roadmap and plan for how we can work together to repair this relationship, communicating more effectively.
- That we do not pay enough attention to feedback and complaints from the Lavender members of our sites and do not take action when necessary as quickly as necessary.
- That we have failed to make the rules apply to everyone equitably and consistently, leaving attacks without real consequences.

A final key thing we are working on (and planning to start implementing gradually) are avenues for improved feedback on projects while they are in progress and before they ship. Depending on each project this could mean focus groups, 1:1 interviews, research, or open calls for feedback. We are committed to working alongside the community and you should be hearing more about it soon.

*The Community Management Team.*

Comment: Finally something worth upvoting. Thank you ❤️ Hopefully, communication can be restored soon

Comment: I don't like to be this antagonistic, but words aren't enough at this point, actions are required. You need to take some clear steps towards fixing the harm you caused Monica, and fixing the situation where transgender users don't feel safe here on meta, in part because of the way SE handled this situation.

Comment: I suggest you substitute a less loaded word in place of "erupt."  In something like this it's helpful to keep your tone as neutral as possible.

Comment: Well, so much betrayal of trust has happened that has made me hesitant to upvote this post. I won't downvote either, however, and wait a few days to see how this will pan out.

Comment: It looks like you guys have some ideas you feel pretty excited about, to help us all get out of the mud pit we're in.  Yay!  (Yay for you guys, that is.)  And of course, any attempt to do active listening is progress, so thank you for that!  But if you really want to get our attention, and show that you're making an honest effort, *please initiate a dialogue with Monica immediately* -- as a first step.  Please drop the bureaucratic preconditions on an initial conversation taking place and get started, *now*.  *Today*.

Comment: Upvote applied. Thank you for listening to us and taking on board what we are saying.

Comment: I see you have "quadrupled your reputation" all of a sudden, as another moderator observed. Congratulations! I am hopeful like Zoe, though I share the concerns of Mad Scientist and Aparente, especially about Monica.

Comment: (1) Since you now recognize that talking to the press like that was wrong, will you be taking any steps to mitigate the damage done by Sara's various public statements (press, main meta, child metas)?  (2) Since you recognize that my removal did not follow due process, will you be reinstating me and then running the new removal process (if warranted), so I can get a fair shake from a sound starting point?  Appealing a verdict that was reached unjustly carries a taint of "guilty until proven innocent" no matter how good your intentions, after all.

Comment: @Magisch I’m just happy to see some acknowledgement and understanding of the problems. It’s a positive step, and I’m glad they didn’t sit on that part.

Comment: Also still concerned about compelled speech of specific words.

Comment: Very encouraging words; I'm just disappointed that the "final step" said nothing about reinstating @Monica ([related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335508/monicas-situation-continues-unresolved-is-SE-hoping-the-problem-just-goes-away)).

Comment: This looks like a step in the right direction, but I still miss any action to mitigate the damage done to Monica. Not even her name is mentioned (like in the so-called [apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/377968)) even though there are clear references to her, or rather what SE did to her.

Comment: Folks: while this letter was _triggered_ by the whole incident surrounding Monica's removal, the letter itself was about broader issues and focused relatively little on the current incident. I don't think it's unreasonable that a response takes a similar line: yes, further steps are required to mitigate the harm done to Monica, but I'm glad to see some positive affirmation of the broader concerns we had. Dealing with the consequences of SE's actions with regards to Monica can still be done elsewhere.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: he didn't say that they recognise any of this. Just that they are aware that the mods and community see it that way.

Comment: This is very encouraging, and I do hope you take this all to heart and follow up with actions to mitigate the current damage, and create policies to prevent similar damage in the future.  It seems like you are very focused on the second part of that, but please don't forget the first.  Remember that we'll all be judging the sincerity of any new policies you come up with based mostly on how you handle the current case.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I meant that Shog's "no comment" post means they recognize talking to the press is wrong, and David's quasi-apology post admitted that they failed to follow a sound process in firing me.  This question and thus this answer is about broader issues, but since Cesar did mention both the press policy and the new processes, I felt it was fair to ask about their application.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, that's fair, but also see my comment -- words on a paper are just that if they make it clear that they're going to ignore them whenever they feel like, and if they come up with a great new policy but *refuse to use it* for Monica's case, that'll be exactly what that indicates.  Obviously they need to address the larger issues as well, but I don't think they can unless/until they address the lack of trust that they've created.

Comment: Of course, @Nate. I sincerely hope they _do_ do something to rectify things with Monica; the latest I've heard is that she'll be able to go through the reinstatement process when it's finalized. Whether that's a sensible option or not... I haven't really decided yet. I was more making the point that if they don't address what they're doing about that _here_, I'm okay with that, as long as they do it somewhere else.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: the no comment policy is just common sense. Every sane company would do that. to protect themselves. it isn't angostura towards you as a person or us as a community.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, not sure if you're missing some context here, but SE *did* talk to a reporter about Monica, including using her real name, so that common sense was not followed, which is why she's asking for a retraction.

Comment: @MonicaCellio wasn't David supposed to contact you directly via email or other private channels?

Comment: More talk, more promises, still no **immediate** action that is necessary to stop harm that keeps being done (to Monica and community). The community waited too long to read more of the same thing. When you push a critically broken build to release, you need to **roll back immediately**, not talk about how the next one will be better (especially when it was promised before).

Comment: @Shadow https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334646/162102

Comment: @NateStrickland: I am fully aware of this. now conclude.

Comment: Not seeing actual actions, just a recap of The Story So Far.

Comment: While it is valuable that a staff member actually acknowledges *some of* the problems that have been raised, I am going to hold off on upvoting this until I see some real action. And real action in my opinion should involve disciplinary action against Sara and full reinstatement of Monica.

Comment: Note that *Monica* isn't mentioned once in this statement.

Comment: Policies are nice.  But what are you _doing_ to reverse the immediate damage?  What are you _doing_ to improve the governance structure so that the demands of your venture capital funders for infinite growth and monetization do not overwhelm healthy stewardship of the community?  What are you _doing_ to address [long-standing problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334573) that are eroding the community's confidence in our stewards?

Comment: @hayd See the link under "this answer". I hope to see some concrete actions soon, hopefully to the positive side.

Comment: I'd actually say, rather ironically that the influx of the very sort of attitudes we hoped to avoid is punishment enough. Rather than focusing on punishment - and there has been enough of that, intentional or otherwise on everyone, we ought to consider how to mitigate and fix the damage

Comment: Withholding my up-vote, because I'm worried that on October 22, I'll want to downvote this.

Comment: @hayd that is correct and I am glad that they are no longer mentioning Monica by name. Communication between her and them should be private and if Monica wants to speak out, that is her choice. By leaving her name out of it they are empowering her to reveal what she wants. Of course this is all predicated on there being private communication and allowing her to go through the reinstatement procedure.

Comment: *"We will share the revised version with the moderators by tomorrow"* Considering that today is Thursday, that would make tomorrow Friday. Surely you aren't even remotely considering shipping on a Friday again...?

Comment: @CodyGray What we're giving to the mods is a draft for feedback not the actual FAQ. We're hoping we can get feedback about the text from the mods to see if we've managed to maintain the tone that Gareth put in his version of the FAQ and if there are statements that they're concerned about. It's about starting a dialogue and getting more eyes on it before we actually launch.

Comment: As happy as I am seeing set dates on communication and references to actually soliciting feedback from moderators, I fear this will only be addressing a couple of symptoms of the greater communication issues, trying to sweep under the rug the licensing and aggressive ad problems

Comment: _The Community Management Team._ - finally something that seems to be the result of a team's effort and is reviewed by more than one person.

Comment: @StrongBad the way Monica has been treated, slandered publicly without any possibility of defense, is - as I understand - the main reason for the upset/resignations. Until her case is satisfied, many users following this will also be unsatisfied, this is hollow.

Comment: 10 business days to come out with "We're working on it" with re-enacting Metas won't be an input... Kind of "Déjà-vu" too much times in the last two years (at least). I don't buy it anymore.

Comment: What does "leaving attacks without real consequences" mean here? The first part of that sentence sounds like it could be referring to Monica's firing, but that was not an "attack" and it did have real consequences. Is it referring to CoC-violating users who have not been punished?

Comment: I will note that while I've upvoted this post based on its content (as one should do), I will point out that it is Just Words and that I'm giving it the token respect of "thanks for those words, I'll await your next action." There is a long road ahead for SE.Inc to regain my trust in your words, but this is at least an acknowledgement of the core issues at stake.

Comment: No voting, just waiting.  I hope actions are taken, although putting Monica through the reinstatement process is still _getting_ _it_ _wrong_, and seems to suggest you guys still don't understand the nature of your mistake.

Comment: @KyleStrand: I assume that point has more to do with LGBT+ mods feeling like meaningful action was not taken in many cases after they reported issues to SE, rather than being about Monica's firing.

Comment: Only took 3 weeks to _acknowledge_ what numerous people have been asking for since day one...hopefully the process of actually fixing things won't be so sluggish.

Comment: You said **That you want to see a roadmap and plan for how we can work together to repair this relationship, communicating more effectively.**, I don't see even one reply to the questions raised by community here. This seems like more *bs* and *blah blah blah* unless **You act on your promises**. Anyone can make promises, but actually doing them would be the challenge.

Comment: The [promised document published on 22nd of October](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes) has received an overall negative feedback.

Comment: @CesarM - "That we do not pay enough attention to feedback and complaints from the Lavender members of our sites and do not take action when necessary as quickly as necessary". It's shocking that SO/Sara feels compelled to actively push the pronoun thing when many from the lavender community say it did *more* harm than good. You're not listening to any of us!

Comment: @Cesar M - "That we do not actively support our Moderators anymore, and thus placed you on shaky ground. Including serious concerns regarding our statements made to the press."  This is not a feel, not an unfounded fear, not a baseless opinionated concern.  As it stands it is demonstrable fact that real-name participation on SE may result in the Company going to the press and harming their volunteers.  And if SE needs to be taken to court to make it right?  We can count on every subsequent event going wrong.  Ego has triumphed.

Comment: Creating and updating employee policies is meaningless if there's no accountability for breaking them and no intent on rectifying the harm caused in doing so.

Comment: @Mark You were on point there.

Comment: “improved feedback on projects while they are in progress and before they ship.“ Are changes to question upvote reputations an example of such improved feedback?

Comment: @Cesar M: It's been a bit over 1 month since this was posted. Since this is not a final response, is there any ETA on when such a reply is expected? This has already been asked here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338313/is-stack-exchange-still-planning-to-respond-to-the-communitys-open-letters but I'm not sure if it's been seen by any staff as of yet.

Comment: I thought it was curious that the list from Cesar did not include 'posting on Meta about new features under consideration or development'.  Mainly because that site is the primary place where moderators actively review how the site works so it seemed like a natural choice to increase communication with the community, and thus how not seeing it in the list seemed a particular oversight.

Comment: // , "That it is not safe or acceptable anymore, even dangerous, to disagree with Stack Exchange on matters of major policy." I thought this was kind of the point of the "Response to the Lavender Letter"? Ban the bigots!

Answer (score 54):

I think the final paragraph summarizes this whole letter:

> We recognise that Stack Exchange is in no way obliged to take our input. We know that we are guests in the home of a private company. We don’t own the platform, and while we want to help to steer the ship, we don’t have the right to determine how it is governed.

This sentiment has been echoed more and more as the community has been ignored and while it's true, it has to be understood that folk have invested a lot of time and effort into building up the communities that currently exist. While that might not mean much to the investors it should at the very least mean something to the CMs. A lot of this is done behind closed doors so we really don't know if many of our concerns have been raised by CMs to the higher-ups, though, I'd like to think they were and that they were shot down by management and not that they were never passed on to management.

> What built this network is a sense of community and common purpose, and a big part of that has always been the close relationship and communication between Stack Exchange and stakeholders, such as moderators and users.

Yes, this is what has always fascinated me personally regarding these sites. The fact that the community plays such a big role. When you look around at other websites where there are huge breaks of trust between mods and highers-ups and no one is ever held accountable the SE sites always stood out. People bash meta (especially MSO) a lot but they really are a blessing in disguise.

and the line which immediately followed it:

> It’s a shame that we’ve lost something so fundamental.

Comment: Re *"folk have invested a lot of time and effort ... might not mean much to the investors"*: It [*does* actually mean a lot to investors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=8m50s) (Stack Overflow is especially mentioned at 9 min 15 secs; the ad ends at 11 min 33 secs).

Answer (score 26):

Comparing the [lavender letter](https://dearstack.artofcode.co.uk/lavender) with the [front-page letter](https://dearstack.artofcode.co.uk/), I am struck by two dramatically different accounts of the Stack's history, and two conflicting visions of action for the future of the site.<sup>1</sup>

The lavender letter describes systemic problems dating back to the beginning of the site, which have been reported and ignored for as long as they've existed. It asks for specific new things, for changes to the status quo which will make the Stack a place to be celebrated rather than a place to be endured.

The front-page letter waxes eloquent about a golden age of cooperation and goodwill, when the Stack listened to concerns and worked with users to correct problems. It asks vaguely for old things, for a return to status quo which will make the Stack be like it used to be.

These are irreconcilable, and the front-page letter's version is the less supportable vision of the site's history.<sup>2</sup> If the Stack has such a great history of supporting its mods, why is mod burnout so common that it's practically memetic, and always has been? Why is the system of mod support reliant on "I'll get back to you" mechanics with single points of failure? Why aren't mods given formal training for dealing with common stressful situations that are part of their job description?

Going back to the way things were just means going to back to the Stack chewing mods up and spitting them out, when vulnerable communities were ignored so thoroughly that other people could avoid noticing the harm at all. Moving forward to a more compassionate, supportive Stack philosophy will improve conditions for *everybody*. And not just for moderators: a true sea change would mean a shift in the Stack's treatment of its ordinary users as fungible content machines, too.

Let's not settle for a return to what some could endure, please. Let's aim for something better than before.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm also struck by the invisibility of the lavender letter: from the front page of the site I would never have known alternate letters existed.

<sup>2</sup> I hesitate to use the word *prelapsarian* but... I counted nearly twenty references to a better time in the past, or the idea that something was working and is now broken, rather than that this is how things have always been. *upset with you right now - There was a time when - as the company has expanded - outlook on the network has become - that has happened over the years - no longer seems to want - the company’s direction over the past year or more - have been increasingly disengaged from the team - It used to be common to see - Moderators were also seen - staff used to be - Now many of them ... feel like strangers - no longer a place - there used to be space - the human touch has been lost - heal this rift - a return to the collaborative model - to see trust ... restored - rebuild*

Comment: Your summation of each letter is overly simplistic. The "Lavender" letter focuses on the systematic inequality of the treatment of LGBTQ+ folk (especially when they are victimized) on Stack Exchange, and that Stack Exchange has an obligation to address that issue as a result of their commitment to the users. The other letter focuses on collaboration, communication, procedure, and trust between the company and the moderators (and the community as a whole). These letters do not compete.

Comment: This is a great point: "Why aren't mods given formal training for dealing with common stressful situations that are part of their job description?"  Thanks for that.

Comment: On footnote 1: The website was made for the other letter, and I don't think the person who made it even knew at the time that the "lavender letter" existed. When they became aware of the "lavender letter" they offered to host it as well, and did it impressively quickly. I don't think it's in any way fair to complain about "the invisibility of the lavender letter" there.

Comment: The front page letter says "We want you to deliver on that promise to trust us, support us, and to give us agency, accountability, and autonomy. Ultimately, we want to feel that we are safe to disagree with Stack Exchange, even on matters of major policy." However, I'd like to point out that a couple of the moderators who resigned recently have publicly made transphobic remarks — one of them specifically citing "moderator agency" in his resignation statement. I think that the the right approach is neither to give moderators full agency nor to blindly rely on a CoC with some simplistic rules.

Comment: @200_success Even in talking about my stance on the issue of gender language I've been careful to separate that from the issue of agency in regard to moderator duties. My resignation post explains _why_ I've separated those issues. I've never suggested blindly giving full agency; I know SE _has never been_ a fully free platform (nor should it be). I've acknowledged that it works best with limits in place and been willing to abide by those limits. Please consider that your accusations are a poor representation / interpretation of the views of people who disagree with you.

Comment: a while ago I studied data provided in SE features change log ([details here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314348/165773)). Per my reading of this data, things indeed were much better in 2013-2014 compared to 2016-2018, and I can see how some may feel like in the past there was kind of a golden age

Comment: I agree with about half of the answer but the other half seems to be an unwarranted attack on the front-page letter. The two accounts are not in conflict. What you call a “golden age” (which is very much an exaggeration of what the letter says) came before the time that the lavender later focuses on. When I started being a moderator in 2011, I didn't always agree with management but I felt they had my back. By 2018 I didn't really feel like they had my back anymore, though it wasn't until Monica's firing that I felt I should be watching for their knife in my back.

Comment: As one of the major drafters of the lavender letter, some notes: the reason the lavender letter isn't visible from the main page of dearstackexchange.com is because it wasn't originally going to be written, until I complained (along with others) about the LGBT+ issues not being addressed. ArtOfCode then quickly put the draft up on the website, and for that I am exceedingly grateful. I personally signed both letters, because I do agree with some of the major points expressed in the main letter (the improper handling of Monica's situation being one) but I do understand and to some extent agree

Comment: [cont.] with your points. I believe that the issues in the lavender letter have been swept under the rug for far too long. Obviously not all agree. Even the lavender letter was rewritten in several parts to be more broadly agreeable.

Comment: The apparent irreconcilability may be in how you're framing things.  e.g., it wasn't that there was a Utopian golden age.  There have always been certain problems for which we have yet to find a solution.  But certain major current issues were unintended consequences of attempted solutions to other problems.  The objective isn't really a return to the old status quo, but a return to the lack of these newer problems, perhaps by finding alternate solutions to what created these problems.  Solutions still need to be found for some of the older problems that never went away.