# How can I influence the future of the network?

Tags: discussion

Meta will no longer be included in the pre-deployment pipeline for changes to the network. How can I make sure that my voice is heard *before* changes are made?

Relevant blog/post:

- [The Loop #1: How we conduct research on the Community team](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/11/the-loop-1-how-we-conduct-research-on-the-community-team/)
- [Donna's answer on Please consider gathering Meta feedback before the “ship” stage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340176/159427)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you'd like the chance to weigh in on future changes before they go live, you'll want to enable the ["research" email setting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current)<sup>1</sup>:

> **Research**
>   
> Invitations to participate in surveys, usability tests, and more. Only a few per year.

Hopefully you'll be selected for any surveys relevant to your interests.

<sub><sup>1</sup> While this setting is applied network-wide, it seems these surveys are only offered to users of [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com) based on their activity, contributions, or whatever criteria the team deems suitable for each survey or test.</sub>

Comment: It might be too late, though.

Comment: It is never too late.

Comment: @YaakovEllis the blog post _explictly says_ that the general audience _will not_ be consulted until it ships, unless the company reaches out to you.

Comment: *At the moment, it seems these surveys are only offered to SO users.* Does that mean that people who participate on other SE's (and never on SO) will not be included in the research phase?

Comment: @dwizum that's my understanding, yes.

Comment: The profile setting applies to all SE sites at once.

Comment: @EmilJeřábeksupportsMonica thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 8):

We have an ongoing site satisfaction survey on SO that is randomly offered to many thousands of users (both active and logged in) every month. If you show up on SO with some moderate frequency, you should eventually see the link. Responses are definitely monitored and can definitely affect things.

Comment: Any plans to open this up to users not on SO? There's lots of good and very active folks that never set foot there.

Comment: I'll start by saying that I definitely appreciate the response, but I agree with @Rubiksmoose: This is a pretty blatant case of SO, Inc. trying to apply a Stack Overflow-specific community management solution to the entire network, which . . . has often gone quite badly in the past. And which will continue to not work going forward.

Comment: We know that there are lots of quality users not on SO. For the time being it is only on SO. Can't make any promises about when it will be wider. But it is something that has been talked about, and want to do at some point.

Comment: Is that to say that the site satisfaction survey is limited to SO or that _all of the surveys_ are limited to SO at this point?

Comment: I am only taking about the randomly sampled site survey. Can't answer about the other ones.

Comment: Is that survey gated behind the email setting as well?

Comment: No. Not gated. Open to all (including anonymous)

Comment: I hope that the effort to pursue input from those who never participate on SO is seriously pursued. Speaking as someone who has never visited SO, but who has hours of participation daily on other community sites, it's very frustrating (to put it mildly) to consider that my opinions are completely excluded if the survey is only ever sent to people on SO.

Comment: Could this link be showing up under one of the many banners that are also often (ab)used to advertise teams, and therefore may be blocked?

Comment: Fascinating. Is there a check in the code that prevents users with moderation privileges from getting this prompt? I’ve *never* seen this, and…I’m on the site a fair amount.

Comment: Currently, you cannot get the survey if you are a member of any team, so that might explain why you don't see it. But there is no mod check. The banner is shown under the topbar and stuck on the bottom left, on question pages (not the homepage). All of this is subject to change, of course. Original survey went out less than half a year ago, and we are planning on potential changes in 2020.

Comment: @YaakovEllis: Ah, then any moderator that's on the Stack Mods team would essentially end up being excluded as a result of that?

Comment: hmm... i *never* use the question page.... only the homepage.

Comment: To be clear, Question page = viewing a question that was asked (most popular route on the site by far). Not asking a question.