# Does "Opt-in to our Research email list" only encompass Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, email-notification, the-loop

> ✋**Opt-in to our Research email list** (must have a Stack Overflow account). You’ll receive invitations to participate in surveys, user interviews, and more. You’ll receive up to a few emails per year and can opt-out at any time.
>   <sub>[The Loop #1: How we conduct research on the Community team](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/11/the-loop-1-how-we-conduct-research-on-the-community-team), December 2019</sub>

I'm thinking about opting in, but it seems limited to Stack Overflow.  I'm not sure though, so...

**Question**: Does "Opt-in to our Research email list" only encompass Stack Overflow?

I'm not active on Stack Overflow, so I'm not particularly interested in its tweaks.  But if it's also about Stack Exchange as a whole, I'd be more interested in joining.

Comment: There are more chances to get the answer by leaving the comment on the blog itself. The SO inc mostly ignore Meta questions and very heavily censor blog comments, but this one may be answered.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Emil Jeřábek supports Monica comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340179/how-can-i-influence-the-future-of-the-network#comment1136903_340180):

> The profile setting applies to all SE sites at once.