# Checking in on the possible changing scope of meta

Tags: support, meta, scope

With the research and feedback being taken from the wider community and less so from meta feedback, it would follow that many of the feature requests and discussions ***may*** not be as relevant on meta.

Also with the staff using blogs and other platforms, it's no longer being used as the sole platform for announcements.

I'm seeking genuine clarification of what to expect of the meta scope.

Will it be drilled down to bug reports?
Does the Network still want feature requests?

Please give us guidance for what you want from the community. I'm asking for an official response.

Is the purpose of meta changing, if so what will it be?

Comment: @user400654 they said they'd be telling us in mid-december, it's not mid-december.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Meta no longer useful for community research?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340199/is-meta-no-longer-useful-for-community-research)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look for more on this in the upcoming posts in The Loop blog series on the company blog. Sorry that more cannot be written at the moment. I can say that these are all pertinent questions that will hopefully be addressed in the coming posts.

Comment: that's still an answer and I appreciate it. Thank you.